# Why the for loop is iterating through 1 item in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I have for loop where the list of URLs should iterate but when I run, the 1st URL (the first item of the list) is iterating again and again.

Here is how my code looks

```
R = []
G = []
B = []
Score = []
URL = []
pixel = []


for image_uri in list_imagefiles[0:2]:
    detect_properties(image_uri)
    for color in dominant_colors.colors:
        
        R.append(color.color.red)
        G.append(color.color.green)
        B.append(color.color.blue)
        Score.append(color.score)
        pixel.append(color.pixel_fraction)
        URL.append(image_uri)
    

df = pd.DataFrame({'URL' : image_uri, 'Red':R, 'Green' : G, 'Blue': B,  'Score' : Score,  'Pixel Fraction': pixel})
```

this is how my output looks... the 3rd and 4th row should be for the second url

```
1   www.example1.com    49.0    42.0    39.0    0.198819    0.222889
2   www.example1.com    224.0   183.0   170.0   0.040362    0.061911
3   www.example1.com    49.0    42.0    39.0    0.198819    0.222889
4   www.example1.com    224.0   183.0   170.0   0.040362    0.061911
```

Comment: How does the output you're getting right now differ from your desired output?

Comment: In definition of df you want `'URL' : URL` rather than `'URL' : image_uri`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your DataFrame, you add `image_uri` as the url values, but this only contains the value from your last loop iteration. Changing it to URL would probably fix it, as it seems as if this is where you store the urls.

`df = pd.DataFrame({'URL' : URL, 'Red':R, 'Green' : G, 'Blue': B,  'Score' : Score,  'Pixel Fraction': pixel})`